# jQuery: Toggle Dropdown Menu Possibility

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, toggle

I have the following HTML below but what I was wanting to know is it possible to use the jQuery `.toggle` function to enable the main `<li>` heading *Trails* to be a link and then when you put the mouse over the main link *Trails* the other pages will show and you can click on the respective page.

**HTML:** - *This HTML formatting is given by PYROCMS and I have no control over it*

```
<li class="current">
        <a href="">Trials</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="first">
                <a href="">Link One</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">Link Two</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">Link Three</a>
            </li>
            <li class="last">
                <a href="">Link Four</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

**jQuery:** - *Could a variation of the below be used for the above issue?*

```
$('select[name="domainTransfer"]').change(function() {

    $('#domainToBeTransfered,#domainToBeTransfered0').toggle($(this).val() === "yes");

    });
```

**Baz1nga:**

I have looked at your jsfiddle and noticed you have placed a `display:none;` on the sub `<ul>` I have placed that into my css the line is `#wrapper #contentarea #blue_box .centerblue_txt ul li ul{` but it does not seem to interact with the jQuery.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $(".current a").mouseenter(function(){
       $(this).siblings("ul").show();
    }).mouseout(function(){
       $(this).siblings("ul").hide();
    });​
});​
```

Comment: You are unlikely to get a good answer if you fail to ask a coherent question. "... the main <ul> heading" - what is a main <ul> heading? "... mouse over the main link" - what main link? "the other pages will show" - what other pages?

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot Have changed the question slightly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".current a").mouseenter(function(){
   $(this).siblings("ul").show();
}).mouseleave(function(){
   $(this).siblings("ul").hide();
});
```

​

Is this what you want?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rY8zm/

Comment: Use mouseenter instead of mouseover and mouseleave instead of mouseout, otherwise if the children spill out of their parent's bounding box, they'll disappear as soon as the mouse cursor is no longer directly within the bounds of the parent.

Comment: sorry my bad I had your structure confused.. see the posted fiddle

Comment: posting a new question is recommended, if its not related

Answer (score 0):

Baz1nga's solution isn't working for me in Opera. The list dies when the cursor transits from the heading to the list - hence the list can be viewed but its links can never be clicked.

You need to take special measures to see the cursor through the transition from element to element. This achieved with a timeout to delay very lightly the hiding of the list; and the canceling of the timeout each time the cursor passes over any element that should keep the list alive.

The code is moderately complex and looks like this:

```
function hideList($list) {
    clearTimeout($list.data('dropdown').tim);
    return setTimeout(function() {
        $list.stop(true).slideUp('slow');
    }, 125);
}

$("li.current").on('mouseover', "a.heading", function() {
    var $list = $(this).siblings("ul").slideDown('slow');
    clearTimeout($list.data('dropdown').tim);
}).on('mouseout', function() {
    var $list = $(this).children("ul");
    $list.data('dropdown').tim = hideList($list);
}).children("ul").on('mouseover', function() {
    clearTimeout($(this).data('dropdown').tim);
}).on('mouseout', function() {
    var $list = $(this);
    $list.data('dropdown').tim = hideList($list);
}).data('dropdown', {
    tim: null
}).hide();
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R2zc5/1/)