# jquery: Uncaught SyntaxError in Dropdown

Tags: jquery, syntax-error

I got the below code from an answer on a previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183659/jquery-toggle-dropdown-menu-possibility).  I have just debugged my code in Chrome and I am getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL on line 6` but all the brackets match up so I am a bit confused.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $(".current a").mouseenter(function(){
       $(this).siblings("ul").show();
    }).mouseout(function(){
       $(this).siblings("ul").hide();
    });​
});​
```

Comment: If you cannot debug it - remove the code and start programming iteratively. Add the lines one by one, checking if it works as expected. If it doesn't - you know for sure what line is wrong

Comment: looks good. Are you sure this is the source of the error? If you remove this code does the error persist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As crazy as it seems the above error was caused by an extra line or space after the closing `;`

Comment: It is not possible. Perhaps it was not literally a space, but something that doesn't have representation in your font/at all. PS: it is a good example that copying-pasting code is never a good idea

Answer (score -2):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".current a").mouseenter(function(){
   $(this).siblings("ul").show();
}).mouseout(function(){
   $(this).siblings("ul").hide();
});​
```

});​

replaced jQuery with $

Comment: jQuery and $ mixed is perfectly valid syntax.